# Kotlin Swap Elements Between Two Arrays WRT To Object Field

Tags: kotlin

I have two ArrayLists that contains a custom object:

```
class MediaData(val path: String,val durationMs: Int)
```

Due to internal complications that are out of topic to this question, I need to swap elements of two ArrayLists that share the same path. For instance:

*Before swap*

```
ArrayList1:
object 1 - path : x, reference:0x12e2e
object 2 - path : y, reference:0x11ad4

ArrayList2:
object 1 - path : x, reference:0x13as2
object 2 - path : z, reference:0x14ed4
```

*After Swap:*

```
ArrayList1:
object 1 - path : x, reference:0x13as2
object 2 - path : y, reference:0x11ad4

ArrayList2:
object 1 - path : x, reference:0x12e2e
object 2 - path : z, reference:0x14ed4
```

Note: look at the object references to understand the differences

Is there a short way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a build-in shortcut for this. You could write a function like this:

```
fun <T> swapMatchingElements(list1: MutableList<T>, list2: MutableList<T>, predicate: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean {
    val index1 = list1.indexOfFirst(predicate)
    if (index1 < 0)
        return false
    val index2 = list2.indexOfFirst(predicate)
    if (index2 < 0)
        return false
    list1[index1] = list2[index2].also { list2[index2] = list1[index1] }
    return true
}
```

Usage:

```
swapMatchingElements(list1, list2) { it.path == "x" }
```